# Why does my MCU go back? (to the previous instruction)

Tags: c, stm32, debugging, ide, stm32f0

I don't know why but I see the same odd behaviour sometimes in the debugger environment. Look at this code (function):

```
static void I2C_TransferConfig(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c,  uint16_t DevAddress, uint8_t Size, uint32_t Mode, uint32_t Request)
{
  uint32_t tmpreg = 0;

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_I2C_ALL_INSTANCE(hi2c->Instance));
  assert_param(IS_TRANSFER_MODE(Mode));
  assert_param(IS_TRANSFER_REQUEST(Request));

  /* Get the CR2 register value */
  tmpreg = hi2c->Instance->CR2;

  /* clear tmpreg specific bits */
  tmpreg &= (uint32_t)~((uint32_t)(I2C_CR2_SADD | I2C_CR2_NBYTES | I2C_CR2_RELOAD | I2C_CR2_AUTOEND | I2C_CR2_RD_WRN | I2C_CR2_START | I2C_CR2_STOP));

  /* update tmpreg */
  tmpreg |= (uint32_t)(((uint32_t)DevAddress & I2C_CR2_SADD) | (((uint32_t)Size << 16 ) & I2C_CR2_NBYTES) | \
            (uint32_t)Mode | (uint32_t)Request);

  /* update CR2 register */
  hi2c->Instance->CR2 = tmpreg;  
}
```

And take a look at this picture of code in the debugger environment:

[image]

When I run it, at first it goes to line 4057 and then it goes to line 4054! Why?

As you can see, both lines are only several variable + several operands! That's all!

Comment: This is likely because of the way the IDE shows you the C source code mixed with the assembly output.  The microcontroller (and simulator) run assembly, but your source code is C.  Each line of C, even simple ones, will result in multiple assembly opcodes.

Comment: @David But this is not a good and acceptale reason. there isn't any reason to do this behaviour. why it should do this behaviour?

Comment: Because although the *overall* behavior of C is specified, it is at the implementer's discretion how these things *actually* happen.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams OOOO! interesting! I already thought that the C codes just run from top to down.

Comment: As you see in the disassembly window, the compiler applied some optimisation and combined the two c assignments into one operation that is below the brown text.

Comment: If you don't want this behavior you can probably compiler without optimizations and/or for debugging. But that will likely make the executable slower and/or larger.

Comment: Placing \$\texttt{__nop();}\$ between the assignments might help to separate them.

Comment: It does not go back, just the IDE is confused about which line to highlight first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard specifies that reads and writes of volatile variables and calls to library routines are considered "observable operations".  A compiler is required to produce an executable which will produce all observable operations in the sequence that the source file directs, but the generated code is change around anything else in the code as it sees fit provided only that all observable operations happen in the same sequence.

For example, if code computes a value, performs an observable operation which does not make use of the value, and then performs one which does, the compiler may decide to perform the first observable operation before computing the value needed for the second.  Given code like:

```
int x = y/z;
if (volatile1)
  volatile2 = x;
```

if the value `x` is never used after the above code, and if variables `y` and `z` are not volatile, a compiler might legitimately decide that the code would be more efficient as

```
if (volatile1)
{
  int x = y/z;
  volatile2 = x;
}
```

since in the situation where `volatile1` is zero it takes less time to execute, and if `volatile1` is non-zero it doesn't take any longer.  Of course, the whole purpose of doing the assignment before testing `volatile` may have been to minimize the elapsed time between reading `volatile1` and writing `volatile2`, but if that's the case if may be helpful to do something like:

```
volatile int dummy_volatile;
#define USE_VALUE(x) (dummy_volatile = (int)(x))
```

and then...

```
int x = y/z;
USE_VALUE(x);
if (volatile1)
  volatile2 = x;
```

That would ensure that an observable operation using the computed value would take place before the observable read of `volatile1`.  Some compilers may offer a means of "observably using" a value without having to actually store it anyplace, but I don't know of any standard means of doing that.

Comment: Or just declare x as volatile so it is clear to the reader what you are actually doing. Alternatively, declare a local dummy variable.

Comment: @Lundin: What do you mean "local dummy variable"?  Isn't that what I started with?  Making `x` volatile would suggest that its value might be needed outside the code that sets it.  By contrast, the purpose of `USE_VALUE` would be to force the compiler to compute its operand.  A routine in an external library which *unbeknownst to the compiler* did nothing but return would work just as well, but on many platforms would probably be slower to execute.  Having code employ a `USE_VALUE(x)` macro makes it possible to easily change code to use the best implementation for each particular compiler.

Comment: What I mean is: `int x = y/z; volatile int dummy = x;`. You declared it as a file scope variable. The macro therefore probably _prevents_ the compiler from doing the best implementation, as the file scope declaration pretty much forbids the compiler to use a temporary stack location or CPU registers to store the variable. And of course, macros are almost always a bad idea because of the decreased readability and lack of type safety. Furthermore, by making the macro globally available, you create a needless tight coupling between unrelated files in the project.

Comment: @Lundin: The idea would be that the macro would be defined in the header of one of the "miscellaneous utility method" files, so that only a single global variable would be needed for the whole project.  Are writes to `volatile` locals whose address isn't taken considered side-effects that must be preserved?